# sed: !p command strange behavior

Tags: sed, numeric-data

Why does the following command print numerical values?

```
$ iostat | sed -n '/[:digit:]/!p'

       1.56    1.38    0.31    0.34    0.03   96.38
```

Comment: `[[:digit:]]` instead of `[:digit:]`

Comment: @cuonglm Ah, yes..merci.

Comment: also, you could use `sed '/[[:digit:]]/d'` or `grep -v '[[:digit:]]'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The the POSIX character class you are trying to use must be placed inside a regular bracket expression, so `[[:digit:]]` not `[:digit:]`. You're also not limited to using just the one character class in the bracket expression, so e.g. `[[:digit:][:punct:]]` or `[^[:digit:]]` can be used.

Your command actually means "print all lines that do not match any of the characters `:`, `d`, `i`, `g` or `t`:

```
$ printf 'a\nd\ni\n:\n'
a
d
i
:
$ printf 'a\nd\ni\n:\n' | sed -n '/[:digit:]/!p'
a
```

What you wanted was:

```
$ iostat | sed -n '/[[:digit:]]/!p'

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
```

Note that newer GNU sed versions (v.4.4 in this example) will print a warning:

```
$ iostat | sed -n '/[:digit:]/!p'
sed: character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]
```